# An internal error has occured. [ invalid access_token, error code 43. ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

When i sign in my APP silently twice with Facebook credential of Firebase,it return this error message.

```
An internal error has occured. [ invalid access_token, error code 43. ]
```

I save the Facebook token in SharedPreferences when first login,and get it when twice login,then create credential with `FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken);` . At last I sign in with this credential using following code:

```
private void signInFirebase(AuthCredential credential, final TaskCompleteListener signInListener) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Logger.i(TAG,"Firebase login success.");
                    } else {
                        Logger.e(TAG,"Firebase login failure:"+task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

It always print like title.
What i have try,and not work:

```
1.change Firebase version from 9.0.2 to 9.4.0
2.search error message in Google directly
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase already persists the user's sign-in state between app restarts. So instead of persisting the Facebook token yourself, [monitor whether the user is already authenticated with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

From that documentation:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance(). addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
        // ...
    }
});
```