# react-native firebase facebook invalid access_token, error code 43 in iPhone

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I use React-Native firebase to facebook login I test in iOS simulator it works! but I test in real device (iPhone 7 plus) but it error log is

```
        userInfo: 
     { FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey: 
        { message: 'invalid access_token, error code 43.',
          errors: 
           [ { domain: 'global',
               message: 'invalid access_token, error code 43.',
               reason: 'invalid' } ],
          code: 400 } },
    message: 'underlying error',
    domain: 'FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain' },
 error_name: 'ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR' },
 domain: 'FIRAuthErrorDomain',
  line: 1794,
  column: 24
```

in my js file is

```
const firebaseAuth = (provider) => {
  return firebaseManager.authorize(provider)

 .then(resp => {
    let cred = null;

  cred = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
    resp.response.credentials.accessToken);

return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred);

})
  .then((data) => {

let request = new Request();
return request.formatCred(data.user).register();
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    throw error
  });
}
```

I already check in [An internal error has occured. [ invalid access_token, error code 43. ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098093/an-internal-error-has-occured-invalid-access-token-error-code-43) but same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An internal error has occured. \[ invalid access\_token, error code 43. \]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098093/an-internal-error-has-occured-invalid-access-token-error-code-43)

Comment: I checked has user it before but it. error again.